# Use a setter in JUnit test without having one in class

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

Lets say I have an entity named `Foo` with an `id` and a `name` (simplified the class):

```
public class Foo {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

In my application I don't want that the `id` is set anywhere manually. Because `foo` will only come from DB. So I don't created a setter for it.

**Now I want JUnit test some method where I want instantiate `foo`. Is there a possibility to set the `id` just for the JUnit Test?**

P.S.: A possible solution is to receive `foo` from the DB first and make the test. But want to avoid the DB call. And I am using `Spring` and `jpa` if its necessary to know.

Comment: `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo, "id", 1L);` something like that.

Comment: You need a setter also if you recieve that data using jpa

Comment: You don't need a setter when using JPA. That depends on the mode you are using (field or property based).

Comment: You can also  use Mockito API's for such requirements

Comment: You can use reflection (search for the keyword, you will find loads of information) or you could extend your class, create your own constructor and overwrite `getId()`. See also [how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes?rq=1)

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. Perfect and easy solution. Never hear of `ReflectionTestUtils` before. If you want to provide an answer I will accept yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for [M. Deinum's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369283/use-a-setter-in-junit-test-without-having-one-in-class#comment64149602_38369283). Easy and perfect solution is to use `ReflectionTestUtils`.

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo, "id", 1L);
  // assertion
}
```

Please note: `ReflectionTestUtils` comes from Spring: `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils`